# How do I deal with placeholders for Win32 error messages?

Tags: winapi

I would like to present meaningful error messages when my program encounters Win32 errors. I call `GetLastError`, and then `FormatMessage`. But some of the error messages contain placeholders. For instance, [`ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx#ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT) has the text:

> %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Presumably, the %1 is meant to be replaced by the name of the module which is not valid. How can I effect that replacement?

Note that I would ideally like a general solution because I note that there are many errors with placeholders. I can see the following messages in the documentation:

- The wrong diskette is in the drive. Insert %2 (Volume Serial Number: %3) into drive %1.
- The operating system cannot run %1.
- This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.
- The image file %1 is signed, unable to modify.
- The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.
- ... and so on.

Comment: Related http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/28/6564257.aspx

Comment: @AlexK. *It bugs me too that system error messages contain %1 insertions that you just have to "know" on a case-by-case basis. -Raymond* Not very encouraging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Raymond Chen effectively answers the question in a comment on his [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071128-00/?p=24353) where he writes:

> It bugs me too that system error messages contain `%1` insertions that you just have to "know" on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 1):

`ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT` contains an insertion %1. You can replace that by using last parameter of `FormatMessage()`. This code a little sample.

```
LPWSTR pMessage = L"%1";
DWORD_PTR pArgs[] = {(DWORD_PTR)L"My_Test_App.exe" }; 

TCHAR buffer[1024];
DWORD dwError = ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT;
DWORD dwFlags = FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY;
DWORD dwResult = FormatMessage(dwFlags, pMessage, dwError, 0, buffer, 1024,  (va_list*)pArgs);
if (dwResult) 
{
    //now, 'buffer' contains below message.

    //
    //My_Test_App.exe is not a valid Win32 application.
    //
}
```

I know that some sytem error codes have insertion. I think we can't supply relevant argument for all of them. So, if I were you, I would like to use just system error code, not `FormatMessage()`. Or, support argument list and `FormatMessage()`for only some frequently system error code.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I have to do this on a case by case basis for each and every possible error code?

Comment: No, definitely not. It's impossible. I think a reason that almost windows application have their own error message format is because this case. I just want to show you how to replace place holder, if you don't know about that.

Comment: @CodeDreamer: when using `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM`, the `lpSource` parameter is not used and can be set to NULL instead of specifying "%1".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yes, you have to deal with insertions on a case by case basis, as different error codes expect different arguments, if any at all.